# Adding list via queryset to ALLOWED_HOSTS

Tags: django, django-settings

I've got objects instances within a class of UserProfile that have a field of  'website' on them. I'd like to take this list of websites from this UserProfile table in my database and append them to the ALLOWED_HOSTS list within the settings.py file in Django. I've figured out how to get the list of websites from the database:

```
   list(UserProfile.objects.all().values_list('website', flat=True)
```

At this point, I don't know how to concatenate this list with the ALLOWED_HOSTS list within the settings.py file. Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a wildcard in [`ALLOWED_HOSTS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts)

> A value of '*' will match anything; in this case you are responsible to provide your own validation of the Host header (perhaps in a middleware; if so this middleware must be listed first in MIDDLEWARE).

Otherwise, you should be able to add the list to settings via

```
from django.conf import settings
settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS.append(list(set(website_list)))
```

where `website_list` is a list of URLs.

Edit to add using list to set to list conversion to ensure no duplicate host values exist.

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of the wildcard, but I'd like to provide validation using ALLOWED_HOSTS if possible.

Comment: Thanks! What file would I add the 2 lines of code to?

Comment: @JasonHoward I really can't say because I don't know your project layout.  About the only issue I can think of is a slowdown if you have a huge number of hosts in that list.  You can see where the check actually happens at https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/request.py#L567